# How to get No of leads, Cost per lead, No of qualifies leads, Cost per qualified lead for Facebook Campaign Using Graph Marketing Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am using Facebook Marketing Api to get Campaign Data. I have Campaign and sights data from facebook marketing api. But i am not able to matric data for campaign.
But i am not able to get No of leads, Cost per lead, No of qualifies leads, Cost per qualified from insights or campaign data using graph marketing api.

Thanks& Regards

[image]